# IntelliJ IDEA does not show newly created classes or files. For the files to see I need to restart the program completely

Tags: java, filereader

I'm working on the IDE IntelliJ and I'm facing an issue that the newly created files are not visible in the workspace it is required to restart the IDE on every time whenever I create a new file.

I'm not sure what I missed during the installation or setup IDE. I appreciate your help. I have attached the screenshot below for your reference.

![[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNuRf.png][1]

![[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxpCE.png][2]

and after:
![ [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSM8W.png][3]

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow!. I fixed the issue on displaying the attached images also added more details related to your question. Kindly review and alter the questions to make it clear for others which will help others to understand and you can get an answer quickly.

Answer (score 0):

try updating intellij idea. Sometimes that seems to be cause

Comment: Hi, solved the problem with classes, but with  creating  new text files no, that is, text files are created (by file.createNewFile();) but not displayed in intelliJ, only after reloading intelliJ.